# Question about (Python/Orange) Apriori associative algorithm

Tags: data-mining, python, orange

I'm trying to wrap my head around [Association rules and frequent itemsets](http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.associate.html).
So I threw my data in, instead of the samples one and sometime it works, sometimes it doesn't.

```
rules = Orange.associate.AssociationRulesSparseInducer(data, support = 0.3)

print "%5s   %5s" % ("supp", "conf")
for r in rules:
    print "%5.3f   %5.3f   %s" % (r.support, r.confidence, r)

inducer = Orange.associate.AssociationRulesSparseInducer(support = 0.2, store_examples = True)
itemsets = inducer.get_itemsets(data)
print itemsets
print data.domain
print [data.domain[i].name for i in itemsets[4][0]]
```

More often than not, itemsets[4][0] shows an `IndexError: list index out of range` error.
So I start playing around with support = 0.3, support = 0.5, support = 0.2 and itemsets[2][0] or itemsets[3][0].

From the docs:

> support
>   Minimal support for the rule. Depending on the data set it should be set to sufficiently high value to avoid running out of working memory (default: 0.3).

True - I tried 0.2 and it quickly blasted my memory on a 800 rows data file.

Any idea what I should do best there or which are viable values for a shopping cart analysis?

800 rows of data (800 orders)
1 to x item(-categories) per order
15 different item-categories in the file, so my data looks like:

```
ItemCat1
ItemCat2, ItemCat2, ItemCat2, ItemCat2, ItemCat7, ItemCat7, ItemCat7,     ItemCat7, ItemCat7
ItemCat1, ItemCat1, ItemCat1, ItemCat1, ItemCat1, ItemCat1, ItemCat1,     ItemCat2
ItemCat4, ItemCat4
ItemCat1, ItemCat1, ItemCat1, ItemCat1, ItemCat1, ItemCat1, ItemCat1,     ItemCat1, ItemCat2
ItemCat5
```

Answer (score 1):

If Python 3 is an option, [Orange 3](http://orange.biolab.si) features FP-growth in its [Orange3-Associate add-on](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Orange3-Associate):

```
pip3 install Orange3-Associate
```

It's well documented: http://orange3-associate.readthedocs.org/

Apriori due to its slowness and resource requirements, as you'd noticed, really isn't an algorithm to consider anymore.

Answer (score -1):

It is not available in Orange, but i would try FP-Growth. Its way faster in combination with low support values than apriori!

Comment: What's not available in Orange?
I actually tried around other libs with Apriori and FP-Growth and indeed you're right, FPG is way faster but the results look a bit different (maybe just because of the lib I used) but still good. I'd go that way I guess.

Comment: for all I know FP-Growth is not available in Orange. The results should be the same for same input data when you use same min-support / min-confidence, but like you said, different libs are using different variants of apriori / FP-growth for better performance.

Comment: Yes, I see. I tried several libs now, FP-Growth as well and it's indeed faster. Still playing around with different libs - Orange seems not that awesome to me after I wrapped my head more around it.

Comment: Orange 3 now seem to feature FP-growth in its Orange3-Associate add-on. Please see the other answer. :)